# Generic with Linq DataContext

Tags: c#, linq, generics

Assume I have a table called **User**. Using LINQ desinger, I will end up with the following:

- A file called **User.dbml**
- A data context class called **UserDataContext** which subclasses from **System.Data.Linq.DataContext**
- A class called User which is mapped from the User table.  A UserDataContext object will have a property called **Users** which is of type **System.Data.Linq.Table<User>**.

So far so good.  Now I want to define a generic base class that converts the Linq.Table property to JSON string for all of its subclasses.  So I would have:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class BasePlugin<T> where T : System.Data.Linq.DataContext, new()
{
    protected T DataContext = new T();
    protected string GetJSONData()
    {            
        //*** DataContext if of type System.Data.Linq.DataContext, therefore it won't know the Linq Table property of its subclasses
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataContext.Cannot_get_subclass_property_Linq_table);
    }
}
```

To complete the code in the question, here's an example of a subclass:

```
class UserPlugin : BasePlugin<UserDataContext>
{
    //The protected member DataContext inherited from BasePlugin 
    //has a property called Users of type System.Data.Linq.Table<User>.
    //The point to to avoid implementing GetJSONData() in all subclasses
}
```

To summarize, the question is how to avoid implementing GetJSONData() in all subclasses by letting the base class do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear which table you'd want. There are potentially several tables in a single data context. There may not be in your particular model, but there certainly can be in LINQ to SQL in general.

You can call `DataContext.GetTable(Type)` or `DataContext.GetTable<T>` if that's useful... and you could parameterize your class by the entity type as well as the context type:

```
class BasePlugin<TContext, TEntity> where TContext : DataContext, new()
    where TEntity : class
{
    protected TContext DataContext = new TContext();
    protected string GetJSONData()
    {            
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataContext.GetTable<TEntity>());
    }
}
```

Is that what you're after?

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I'm after.  It looks like GetType<TEntity>() causes a compilation error and GetType() would simply be enough, so the second parameterized argument TEntity is not needed?

Comment: @Khnle: You just need a class constraint on TEntity. Will update the code. You also need to call GetTable, not GetType - typo on my part.