# LinqToSql query loading unwanted data into memory

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am simulating a join on a linked server through linq to sql. My question is, it appears that linqtosql is bringing all the rows for y.Xstatuses into memory and then doing the join. **If this is true how do i keep all the memory on sql server(and still do a cross datacontext join operation), if this not true what is going on that is eating all my ram?**

```
var x = new fooDataContext();
var y = new barDataContext();

var allXNotDeleted = (from w in x.CoolTable
                      where x.IsDeleted != false).ToList();//for our demo this returns 218 records

var allXWithCompleteStatus = (from notDeleted in allXNotDeleted
                              join s in y.XStatuses on notDeleted.StatusID equals s.StatusID
                              where s.StatusID == 1
                              select notDeleted).Tolist();// insert massive memory gobbler here

return allXwithCompleteStatus;
```

EDIT:
Trying to implement Kevinbabcock's idea

```
    using (x = new fooDataContext())
    using (var y = new barDataContext())
    {

        var n = (from notDeleted in x.GetTable<CoolTable>()
             join z in y.GetTable<Xstatus>() on x.StatusID equals z.StatusID
             where z.StatusID == 1 and x.IsDeleted != false
             select x).ToList();

    }
```

This still throws a cross context query exeception

Comment: Do you need to call `ToList` on `allXNotDeleted`?

Comment: @DanielKelley no, i don't need to call tolist. it is there to show that when the query is enumerated that the memory hog occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to perform cross data context query directly on the database.
Fetching in memory one of the recordset (ToList()) forces anyway the other joined to be processed in memory.

If you want to perform everything on sql server you have to have every entity in the same DataContext.

Comment: mdn is Correct that only a single `DataContext` can be used if you want to execute everything in SQL Server. However, it should be noted that you don't have to have all your entities mapped to the same derived `DataContext` class. You can use the `DataContext` base class and call `GetTable<TEntity>()` for each mapped table you want to query, regardless of whether the tables are mapped in the same class.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but I have rarely seen using ling2sql without the VS editor, or calling directly its methods, despite there are a lot of powerful features moreover with DataContext subclassing.

Comment: @kevinbabock I tried implementing your idea but it still blows up

Comment: @KevinBabcock talks about subclassing not nested usings. Nested using is the same as calling in a separate way. Subclassing is something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105148/generic-with-linq-datacontext  a class extending the first datacontext.

Comment: @mdn I rarely see that sort of thing either. In projects that use LINQ to SQL I only use the designer to map objects. I use the `DataContex` base class exclusively to perform database operations. When the LINQ to SQL code generator produces derived `DataContext` classes (e.g. `CustomerDataContext`), the extra properties it exposes to query your tables simply abstract a call to `GetTable<TEntity>()`. Using the base class allows you to call `GetTable<TEntity>` on multiple classes across several mapping files in the same query. Like you said, there are more powerful features than most people use.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I'd recommend not calling `ToList` on `allXNotDeleted` for a start. That will pull those records into memory, which will probably mean that you can't avoid pulling all the other data into memory when you perform your second query.</s>

EDIT:

As an additional note if your tables are particularly big, and you only need data from a few columns, you could set `Delay Loaded` to `True` in your database object models for the columns you don't need.

EDIT2:

I have just noticed both queries come from different contexts. In that case I suggest you create a stored procedure and call that from one of the contexts. The sproc should be responsible for spanning the contexts.

Comment: I will try, but all tolist does is show that when the query is executed the memory usage spikes significantly. Be it executed in the DAL or when the UI tries to enumerate over the result set.

Comment: Calling `.ToList()` on `allXWithCompleteStatus` is fine, as at some point you will need to actually execute the query. However, I believe that calling `.ToList()` on `allXNotDeleted` causes all of your query to operate in memory.

Comment: @DaneilKelley is there a magic operator that I can call which will force the set to be enumerated over  on sql server then the result sent back to me?

Comment: @gh9 I just noticed (thanks to mdn's answer) that both queries come from different contexts. In that case I'd recommend writing a stored procedure that can be called from one of the context's that will span the sources.

Answer (score 0):

Do not call `ToList()` on `allXNotDeleted`. This materializes those records in memory, which will cause the entire `XStatuses` table to also be materialized in memory to perform the join.

Try this:

```
using(var context = new DataContext(connectionString))
{
    var allXNotDeleted =
        from w in context.GetTable<CoolTable>()
        where x.IsDeleted != false;
    var allXWithCompleteStatus = (
        from notDeleted in allXNotDeleted
        join s in context.GetTable<XStatuses>()
            on notDeleted.StatusID equals s.StatusID
        where s.StatusID == 1
        select notDeleted)
        .ToList();
    return allXwithCompleteStatus;
}
```

This will only send a single query to SQL Server, and will only materialize the "notDeleted" values returned from the query. Don't forget to wrap your `DataContext` instance in using statements so that `Dispose()` is properly called when they go out of context.

Also, did you mean to filter `CoolTable` with `IsDeleted != false`? This is equivalent to `IsDeleted == true`, which to me indicates that you want to join all deleted records (which the name of your variable, `allXNotDeleted`, seems to contradict).

EDIT: updated code to work with a single `DataContext` instance, which should eliminate the "query contains a reference to another DataContext" error. You will need to pass in the `ConnectionString` to the `DataContext` constructor if you're not using a derived `DataContext` class.

Comment: When I run that i get the Query contains references to another datacontext error.

Comment: @KevinBabock crappy naming in the example sorry

Comment: @kevinBabock I updated my question with your suggestion and it still is not happy

Comment: You are still using two `DataContext` instances. Use only one, an instance of the base `DataContext` class, as described in my answer.